# How get var value from return in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know if my question is right as in the title.
generally, I have this code:

```js
function one(){
    var main= document.getElementById('main');
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e']; 
    var btn = document.createEement('button');
    var btnTxt= document.createTextNode('click');
    main.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(btnTxt);
    btn.setAttribute('onclick','two()');
    return arr;
}

function two() {
    //I need to get the arr variable here.
}
```

Comment: Just call the `one` function in `two`. accept it in a variable

Comment: You need to set the var `arr` outside of function one. But you can override it in function one. Now its scoped to function one so you dont have access to it in function two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function `one()` in two because its `return` the `arr`.Also you don't have div with `id = main` so I added it
**Note**: The function `one()` will be called on each click of `btn` so new `btns` will be created

```js
function one(){
  var main= document.getElementById('main');
  var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e']; 
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  var btnTxt= document.createTextNode('click');
  main.appendChild(btn);
  btn.appendChild(btnTxt);
  btn.setAttribute('onclick','two()');
  return arr;
}
one();
function two(){
   var arr = one();
   console.log(arr);
//  i need to get the arr varible here.
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set a variable equal to the function.

`var oneResult = one();`

```js
function one(){
    var main= document.getElementById('main');
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    var btnTxt= document.createTextNode('click');
    main.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(btnTxt);
    btn.setAttribute('onclick','two()');
    return arr;
}

function two(){
    // i need to get the arr varible here.
    var oneResult = one();
}

two();
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: And the fact that `one()` adds a button that when clicked calls `two()` isn't suspicious?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not quite sure of the issue... So clicking the button created by `one()` is essentially going to create a duplicate button. Is there any issue I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to pass `arr` as argument of function `two` using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Note if you call `one()` inside function `two()` a new button will be created every time:

```js
function one()
{
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    var btnTxt= document.createTextNode('click');
    main.appendChild(btn);
    btn.appendChild(btnTxt);
    btn.setAttribute('onclick',`two(${JSON.stringify(arr)})`);
    return arr;
}

function two(arr)
{
    //I need to get the arr variable here.
    console.log(arr);
}

one();
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: only your solution will not call the `one()` multiple times. +1

Answer (score 0):

call the one function in two

```js
function one(){
var main= document.getElementById('main');
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e']; 
var btn = document.createEement('button');
var btnTxt= document.createTextNode('click');
main.appendChild(btn);
btn.appendChild(btnTxt);
btn.setAttribute('onclick','two()');
return arr;
}

function two(){
var v=one();
//  i need to get the arr varible here.
}
```